# Different behavior on Running Unix Commands from Java on GitBash Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, bash, command

I am trying to run some Unix commands by using Java on both Windows GitBash and Linux bash (AWS EC2 instance).

Code is here [Open git bash using ProcessBuilder and execute command in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189986/open-git-bash-using-processbuilder-and-execute-command-in-it)

However, the same code works perfectly fine on Linux and fails under Windows GithBash.

This is the command passed to the ProcessBuilder which give trouble

```
   String Message = "Something+here:HH::1234'Description One+Possible spaces'Something else::here'AnotherDescription'Another One:12345'Description'";

   String cmd1 = "echo \"" + Message + "\" > " + destinationPath;
```

I need to include the quotes and spaces in the Message.

What could be the reason of this difference?

In Windows GitBash I get the message partially prompted. Don't get past the first space. File is not created, quote is not displayed:

```
> Trying to execute command echo "Something+here:HH::1234Description One+Possible spaces Something else::hereAnotherDescription Another One:12345Description" > destinationPath
> Something+here:HH::1234Description
```

single quotes are not showed.

While in Linux the all Message is prompted and file is created:

```
> Trying to execute echo "Something+here:HH::1234'Description One+Possible spaces'Something else::here'AnotherDescription'Another One:12345'Description'" > destinationPath
```

single quotes are showed and file is created.

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: You generally *don't* need to quote stuff if you're using `ProcessBuilder` properly. `echo` is a shell built-in, so you need to invoke the shell interpreter on each system explicitly. That will probably be `bash` on Linux and `cmd` on Windows

Comment: Thanks for comment. So if invoke cmd instead a GitBash it will be fine?
In this case is the echo command but

Comment: I run it with "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe" under Windows, do I need to use cmd.exe instead?

Comment: Actually, in Linux, `echo` is also an executable. But nonetheless, it might be better to treat it as the built-in one instead, then you have 'symmetry' between the two OSs. You also have a redirect, which is most definitely a shell interpreter thing. I don't know git-bash.exe but I would guess it would behave like bash w.r.t. echo. Make sure you inherit IO in `ProcessBuilder` so you see it print to stdout